# What is automatically running apt update?

Tags: debian, systemd, apt

I have a debian 9 server where it appears that `apt update` is being run by something. I find this by running `ls -l /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` and noticing a recent date (more recent than the last time I manually ran apt update). The change to this file is happening every day at exactly the same time.

At the same time I found the following in syslogs `systemd[1]: Started /usr/bin/apt-get --just-print upgrade`

But I can't find what has caused this to run.

- There are no system timers running
- It's not the cron job in `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat`
- There are no other cron jobs doing it
- Unattended upgrades is not installed
- apticron is not installed
- cron-apt is not installed

Comment: Try ls /lib/systemd/apt*.

Comment: Do you have `unattended-upgrades` installed?

Comment: What would I be looking for in /lib/systemd ? The config for the timers are there, but I have disabled the timers so they don't run.

No I don't have unattended-upgrades installed, see main post.

Another piece of information is that the change to pkgcache.bin happens at EXACTLY the same time every day